# Show that $X_n = n \min(T_1,T_2 \cdots T_n )$ has assymtoticaly an exponential distribution as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence

> Let,  $T_1,T_2 \cdots T_n $ be i.i.d random variables having reliability function:

$$R-(t) = 1 - \lambda t - o(t) \quad\text{ as }\quad t \rightarrow 0$$.

> Show that $X_n = n \min(T_1,T_2 \cdots T_n )$ has assymtoticaly an exponential distribution as $n \rightarrow \infty$
>
> > **Note:** $F(t) = 1 - R(t)$ , $F(t)$ being the cdf.

**What I have done so far is:**

> 1.) Calculated the cdf of $\min(T_1,T_2 \cdots T_n )$, which is:
>           $[ 1 - {R(t)}^n ]$
>
> 2.) Put this value and obtain the cdf of $X_n$, which results in:
>           **n $[ 1 - {(1 - \lambda t - o(t))}^n ]$**

After that I am lost.

Comment: As usual with minima, one should try to estimate $P(X_n>x)$ for some fixed $x$, when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Did I have added what I have done. p.s. please comment

Comment: Your point 2) is careless and wrong: If the CDF of $X_n/n$ is $1-(1-R(t))^n$, the CDF of $X_n$ is...

Comment: @Did Its should be...  $1/n *$ cdf of $ X_n/n$

Comment: "Its should be... 1/n∗cdfofXn/n" What? No, really no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,
$$
\mathsf{P}(\min\{T_1,\dots,T_n \}\le t)=\mathsf{P}(X_n/n\le t)=1-[R(t)]^n.
$$
Then
$$
\mathsf{P}(X_n \le t)=\mathsf{P}(X_n/n \le t/n)=1-[R(t/n)]^n\rightarrow 1-e^{-\lambda t}
$$

as $n\rightarrow \infty$ by plugging the expansion of $R(t/n)$ around $0$.